# Ansible: fortigate list to popolate a dictionary

Tags: loops, ansible, fortigate

```
remote_address_phase2:
  - 192.168.88.0/24
  - 192.168.1.0/24
```

task:

```
i have to create a firewall group 

  - name: "addrgrp"
    fortios_firewall_addrgrp:
      vdom:  "{{ vdom }}"
      state: "present"
      firewall_addrgrp:
        allow_routing: "disable"
        #category: "default"
        color: "21"
        comment: "try"
        exclude: "disable"
        fabric_object: "disable"
        member:
          - name: "NET-{{ item}}"
      
        name: "try"

        type: "default"

    with_items:  "{{  remote_address_phase2 }}"
```

if i made this activity i have 2 different task but the last operation overwrite the first

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the example in the documentation for the [module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/fortios_firewall_addrgrp_module.html), it seems that the `member:` parameter takes a list of dicts.

Example from module documentation:

```yaml
        member:
         -
            name: "default_name_7 (source firewall.address.name firewall.addrgrp.name)"
```

Haven't tested it, but we can create a similar structure before `"addrgrp"` task with `set_fact` and use the newly created variable.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        fw_members: "{{ fw_members | default([]) + [{'name': 'NET-' ~ item}] }}"
      loop: "{{ remote_address_phase2 }}"
```

This gives:

```
    "fw_members": [
        {
            "name": "NET-192.168.88.0/24"
        },
        {
            "name": "NET-192.168.1.0/24"
        }
    ]
```

It should then be possible to pass this variable as a value to the `member:` parameter. Example:

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      fw_members: "{{ fw_members | default([]) + [{'name': 'NET-' ~ item}] }}"
    loop: "{{ remote_address_phase2 }}"

  - name: "addrgrp"
    fortios_firewall_addrgrp:
      vdom:  "{{ vdom }}"
      state: "present"
      firewall_addrgrp:
        allow_routing: "disable"
        #category: "default"
        color: "21"
        comment: "try"
        exclude: "disable"
        fabric_object: "disable"
        member: "{{ fw_members }}"
        name: "try"
        type: "default"
```

Comment: works many thanks